# Is there a way for the SCIP optimization software to write the model into an LP / MPS file

Tags: linear-programming, scip

Some commercial solvers like GuRoBi have a nifty function which can be used to write the optimization problem to a `.lp` file or a `.mps` file. For instance,GuRoBi python interface has this command,

```
model.write("test.lp")
```

I am using SCIP's `c++` interface I was wondering if I can write the model I described in `c++` to an `lp` file. Googling seems to just give me answers about reading .lp files and not writing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call [SCIPwriteOrigProblem](https://scip.zib.de/doc-6.0.2/html/group__GlobalProblemMethods.php#gaf882d322c96b7edf4ae4240e6f35d4b5).

Example:

```
int retcode = SCIPwriteOrigProblem(scip, "test.lp", NULL, FALSE);
assert(retcode == SCIP_OKAY);
```